# ScrollView make my layout smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I tried put a `ScrollView` before all layouts I have in mainActivity, it wasn't working because the error - `ScrollView` can have onlu one child. So I wrapped all view in `LinearLayout` (as adviced on stackoverflow), but t totally messem my design. I need display whole screen layout, but instead its height is smaller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#d5bad9"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Team A"
                        android:textColor="#616161"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="56sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="addGoalA"
                        android:text="GOAL" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyA"
                        android:text="Penalty" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty_goal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalA"
                        android:text="penalty goal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Team B"
                        android:textColor="#616161"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="56sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="addGoalB"
                        android:text="GOAL" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyB"
                        android:text="penalty" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty_goal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalB"
                        android:text="penalty goal" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="resetScore"
                android:text="RESET" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: 1. LinearLayout after the ScrollView looks unnecessary. 2. Try android:fillViewport = true on ScrollView.

Comment: Try setting your parent linear layout height and width as match parent as they will take up all the space and in my opinion shouldnt conflict with the ScrollView and also get in the habit of using match parent instead of fill parent. Fill parent is renamed to match parent in API lvl 8 and higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`fill_parent`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) is deprecated you need to use  [**`match_parent`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) also make [**`android:fillViewport="true"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) in your `ScrollView`

make change in your layout like below code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

**SAPMLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#d5bad9"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                match_parent

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                            android:paddingTop="16dp"
                            android:text="Team A"
                            android:textColor="#616161"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="56sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:onClick="addGoalA"
                            android:text="GOAL" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:onClick="addPenaltyA"
                            android:text="Penalty" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty_goal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalA"
                            android:text="penalty goal" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                            android:paddingTop="16dp"
                            android:text="Team B"
                            android:textColor="#616161"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="56sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:onClick="addGoalB"
                            android:text="GOAL" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:onClick="addPenaltyB"
                            android:text="penalty" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty_goal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="35dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalB"
                            android:text="penalty goal" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:onClick="resetScore"
                    android:text="RESET" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @mgloss happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 use this in ScrollView and dont use any waight
```

> android:fillViewport="true"

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#d5bad9"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Team A"
                        android:textColor="#616161"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="56sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="addGoalA"
                        android:text="GOAL" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyA"
                        android:text="Penalty" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_a_score_penalty_goal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalA"
                        android:text="penalty goal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Team B"
                        android:textColor="#616161"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="56sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="addGoalB"
                        android:text="GOAL" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyB"
                        android:text="penalty" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team_b_score_penalty_goal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="35dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:onClick="addPenaltyGoalB"
                        android:text="penalty goal" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="resetScore"
                android:text="RESET" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```